# Docker Compose Link and Network

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

Estou usando *Docker Compose* para subir meus *containers* no *Docker*, o problema que estou tendo é fazer o link entre um container e outro. Meu *Docker Compose*:

```
version: '3'
services:
  DB:
    image: postgres:9.6.0
    ports:
      - "5430:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydatabase
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    container_name: lx-gulp-db
  API:
    image: lx-gulp:api
    ports:
      - "8200:8080"
    container_name: lx-gulp-api
    depends_on:
      - DB
    links:
      - "DB:lx-gulp-db"
  WEB:
    image: lx-gulp:web
    ports:
      - "8008:8080"
    container_name: lx-gulp-web
    links:
      - "API:lx-gulp-api"
```

*Docker-compose up DB* está **OK**!

*Docker-compose up API* **não funciona**!

Estou usando *Spring Boot* para o *container* API e a mensagem a seguir aparece no terminal:

> Connection to lx-plug-tributacao-db:5430 refused.  Check that the
>   hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting
>   TCP/IP connections.

Minha *application.yml*:

```
spring:
  profiles: production
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://lx-gulp-db:5430/mydatabase
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    test-on-borrow: true
    validation-query: SELECT 1 FROM dual
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate

  jackson:
    serialization:
      WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
    date-format: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat
server:
  port: 8080
flyway:
  schemas: public
```

**Aviso**: estou usando Ubuntu como S.O.

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Este é o Stack Overflow em português, procure fazer perguntas em inglês no Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, lendo a documentação do *Docker* cheguei à conclusão, e vou tentar explicar aqui.

Quando usamos um *Container* com link para um outro *Container*, o *Docker* já entende que a navegação entre as camadas será pela rede interna dele próprio, o *Container* a ser visualizado deve então tratar as portas internas e não as externas. Por exemplo:

Aqui tenho meu *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'
services:
  DB:
    image: postgres:9.6.0
    ports:
      - "5430:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydatabase
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    container_name: mydatabase
  API:
    image: myrepository:api
    ports:
      - "8200:8080"
    container_name: myapi
    depends_on:
      - DB
    links:
      - "DB:lx-gulp-db"
```

Para acesso externo, tanto no *Container* **DB** quanto no *Container* **API** eu usarei as portas exportadas. no exemplo acima eu usei a porta **5430** para o *Container* **DB** e a porta **8200** para o *Container* **API**.
Considerando que meu *Container* **API** precisa acessar o *Container* **DB**, o arquivo de configurações precisa apontar para a porta interna e não a exportada.

Exemplo usando o *Spring Boot* no arquivo de configurações *application.yml*:

```
spring:
  profiles: production
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://lx-gulp-db:5432/mydatabase
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    test-on-borrow: true
    validation-query: SELECT 1 FROM dual
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate

  jackson:
    serialization:
      WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
    date-format: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat
server:
  port: 8080
flyway:
  schemas: public
```

Observa-se, que estou apontando pra porta **5432** que é a porta interna do *Container* que vou fazer o link. Dessa forma, a comunicação é sucedida  após o comando:

```
docker-compose up
```